# Could not get unknown property 'compile' for configuration container

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

Need Help: I'm trying to upgrade the gradle version to 7.4.2 but seeing the following error

> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating root project 'service'.
>   Could not get unknown property 'compile' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.

It is coming from the below lines of code

```
war{

    archiveName 'xyz-svc-clt.war'
    
    manifest{
        attributes "Weblogic-Application-Version":  getBuildVersion(),
                   "Built-By": "${env.USERNAME}",
                   "Built-On": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"), 
                   "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
        
    }
    
    if (isDev() == false){
        rootSpec.exclude("**/*_log4j.xml")
        rootSpec.exclude("**/*.properties")
    }   
    
    from('src/main/resources/'){
        include 'handler-chain.xml'
        into 'WEB-INF/classes/com/abc/xyz/service/xyzService/'      
    }
    
    from('src/main/resources/'){
        include 'handler-chain.xml'
        into 'WEB-INF/classes/com/abc/xyz/service/xyzService/notification/'
    }   
}
```

I looked at similar kind of questions and tried different solutions but nothing worked for me. Modified configurations.compile to configurations.implementation after adding the below line but it didn't work.

```
project.configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
```

Also I have the below plugins in my code

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
```

Comment: most likely to do with plugins section ; ensure that java or war is defined.

Comment: I already added both the plugins 
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

Answer (score 1):

Below change worked for me

```
war{

    archiveName 'xyz-svc-clt.war'
    
    manifest{
        attributes "Weblogic-Application-Version":  getBuildVersion(),
                   "Built-By": "${env.USERNAME}",
                   "Built-On": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"), 
                   "Class-Path": configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
        
    }
    
    if (isDev() == false){
        rootSpec.exclude("**/*_log4j.xml")
        rootSpec.exclude("**/*.properties")
    }   
    
    from('src/main/resources/'){
        include 'handler-chain.xml'
        into 'WEB-INF/classes/com/abc/xyz/service/xyzService/'      
    }
    
    from('src/main/resources/'){
        include 'handler-chain.xml'
        into 'WEB-INF/classes/com/abc/xyz/service/xyzService/notification/'
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you! the relevant update was from "compile" to "compileClasspath"
"Class-Path": configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.absolutePath }.join(" ")